# MNIST dataset not found

Tags: mnist

I'm trying to run the command (that should download dataset of images) on terminal

```
wget http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz
```

this is the first step in a lot of deep learning guides.

but I am getting:

```
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
bash: line 1: `<!DOCTYPE html>'
--2020-11-21 19:35:21--  http://deeplearning.net/data/mnist/mnist.pkl.gz
Resolving deeplearning.net (deeplearning.net)... 132.204.26.28
Connecting to deeplearning.net (deeplearning.net)|132.204.26.28|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2020-11-21 19:35:21 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

can you please help me understand the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I think their servers are currently down.

Meanwhile, you can manually download the whole dataset from [here](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)